# How to combine properties defined by different parent classes in python?

Tags: python, properties, multiple-inheritance

Suppose we have two classes and each computes a property `stuff` in a different way. Is is possible to combine their outputs in a method/property of a child class?

The following code shows the desired effect (though `get_stuff_from` needs to be replaced by a proper python construct, if such thing exists).

```py
class Foo():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return ['a','b','c']

class Bar():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return ['1','2','3']

class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    @property
    def stuff(self):

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Foo().stuff
        foo_stuff = get_stuff_from(Foo)

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Bar().stuff
        bar_stuff = get_stuff_from(Bar)

        # Returns the combined results
        return foo_stuff + bar_stuff

foo_bar = FooBar()
print(foo_bar.stuff)
```

which should output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']
```

If `stuff` were a *method* instead of a property, this would be simple to implement:

```py
class Foo():
    def stuff(self):
        return ['a','b','c']

class Bar():
    def stuff(self):
        return ['1','2','3']

class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    def stuff(self):

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Foo().stuff
        foo_stuff = Foo.stuff(self)

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Bar().stuff
        bar_stuff = Bar.stuff(self)

        # Returns the combined results
        return foo_stuff + bar_stuff

foo_bar = FooBar()
print(foo_bar.stuff())
```

however, I would like to find out whether it is possible to do the same with properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is just an object with an `fget` method. You could access the base class' property object and invoke its `fget` method with the `self` object that refers to the child class:

```
class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    @property
    def stuff(self):

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Foo().stuff
        foo_stuff = Foo.stuff.fget(self)

        # Computes stuff from the internal state like Bar().stuff
        bar_stuff = Bar.stuff.fget(self)

        # Returns the combined results
        return foo_stuff + bar_stuff
```

And now `FooBar().stuff` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 1):

Having two parents using the same name for two different things is a conflict you should fix *before* inheriting. Usually, this means using at least one adaptor class.

```
class Foo():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return ['a','b','c']

class Bar():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return ['1','2','3']


class BarAdaptor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = Bar()

    @property
    def bar_stuff(self):
        return self.b.stuff


class FooBar(Foo, BarAdaptor):
    # Don't repeat or perpetuate the mistake of
    # overloading stuff to mean different things.
    @property
    def foobar_stuff(self):
        return self.stuff + self.bar_stuff
```

For symmetry, you might want to adapt `Foo` *and* `Bar`.

This is inspired by the advice for incorporating non-cooperative classes into a hierarchy of cooperative multiple inheritance classes, outlined in [Python's `super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Thanks, the adaptor is a good suggestion (though not the ideal solution in my case, as it tends to make things too verbose).  Though I must point that having properties with the same name in different classes is not (necessarily) *a mistake*. For instance, output of the properties could mean exactly the same thing, but the way it is computed (in each parent class which are being combined) may be different.

Comment: But that's not the case in your question. If the only difference was in *how* the result was compute, there would be no reason to combine the results of both properties; you would be happy to use whichever the attribute lookup algorithm happened to find.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, otherwise I don't know why you're deriving from Foo and Bar. In your current code you were just overwriting these properties.

```py
class Foo():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return self._foo_stuff
    @property
    def _foo_stuff(self):
        return ['a','b','c']
class Bar():
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return self._bar_stuff
    @property
    def _bar_stuff(self):
        return ['1','2','3']
class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return self._foo_bar_stuff
    @property
    def _foo_bar_stuff(self):
        return self._foo_stuff + self._bar_stuff
foo_bar = FooBar()
print(foo_bar.stuff)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the code below

```
class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.bar = Bar()

    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return self.foo.stuff + self.bar.stuff
```

Comment: This runs into problems if you consider that `Foo` or `Bar` might have properties that return attributes modified after their `__init__` was run.